# Lah numbers and Stirling numbers relation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, stirling-numbers

The generalized Stirling number is $S(n,k;\alpha,\beta,r)$ where the special case $S(n,k;-1,1,0)$ is the Lah number, $$S(n,k;-1,1,0)=\frac{n!}{k!}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}$$ I wonder if there is any well-known form for $S(n,k;-1,-b,0)$. Even if there is no name for it, is there a clean (factorial-based) representation for it similar to Lah number's?

Comment: Perhaps you will find what you are looking for in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.3306v1.pdf .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.5251v1.pdf), this set of generalized Stirling numbers may be given, when $ n \ne 0$ by:
$$
S(n,k;-1,-b,0) = \frac{1}{(-b)^k k!} \sum_{j = 0}^n (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} ((j-k)b)^\overline{n}
$$
Where $ (\cdot)^\overline{n} $ denotes the rising factorial. Due to the binomial coefficient, when $ j > k $ , the summand is zero. Due to the rising factorial, while $ j \le k $ the summand is zero, thus making the entire sum zero.

When $ n = 0$ :
$$
S(0,k;a, b, c) = \delta_{0,k}
$$

Therefore, the item is very well known and is commonly used, either $ 1 $ while $ n = k = 0 $ or $ 0 $ otherwise.

Comment: can you give a reference for the explicit formula of generalized Stirling numbers you mentioned?

Comment: Corollary 2.3 from the referenced link, applied to the given parameters, then simplified by reducing their generalized factorial by equation 1.9.

Comment: The Corollary 2.3 doesn't look correct. The summation must range from $j=0$ to $k$. Currently it ranges from $j=0$ to $n$.

Comment: Are you looking at equation 2.3? Because corollary 2.3, which is equation 2.9, goes from 0 to n.

Comment: yeah, it should go from 0 to k

Comment: What makes you believe that it should have those bounds?

Comment: It doesn't recover the Stirling number of 2nd kind, for instance. To recover that the range must be from 0 to k.

Comment: When j > k, the summand becomes zero. Therefore, from k+1 to n, the terms add nothing and it gives an equivalent sum to the sum from 0 to k. You can check computationally, but this recovers the Stirling numbers of the second kind with S(n,k,0,1,0), see for instance example 2.1 or equation 2.8.

Comment: nicely spotted!